# alternative of adx com addin provided by add in express for developing outlook addin

Tags: .net, outlook-addin

I want to develop a version independent outlook addin using visual studio2010.
Is any other option rather than adx com addin available ?

Answer (score 0):

Add-in Express provides its own [IDTExtensibility2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.aspx) implementation with a shim. You are free to develop a raw implementation too.

Paid edititions of Visual Studio deliver VSTO out of the box. It is another implementation (Microsoft's) of the [IDTExtensibility2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.aspx) interface.

Comment: Then exactly which  tool is used for developing version independent outlook addin in visual studio